# How to stop Indy from converting characters in XML to codes

Tags: xml, delphi, indy

I'm trying to use a third-party web API, which expects the request body to be a XML document, but the XML that the server is receiving is being rejected as not well formed, since Indy has replaced a bunch of characters with ANSI codes.

I'm using XE2 and Indy 10.5.8.0.

I already noticed that Indy is converting CRLF to &, so took all those out of the source XML. Now while the TStringList that I am passing to .Post contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><AdCourierAPI>
```

The server is seeing:

```
%3C%3Fxml+version=%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3CAdCourierAPI%3E
```

How do I stop Indy from doing that? Do I need to change the encoding?

Here is the code for one of the API methods:

```
function TBroadBeanAPI.ListChannels(const AUserName, APassword: String): String;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  ASource: TStringList;
  XMLRequest: String;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
  ASource := TStringList.Create;

  Result := '';

  try
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    HTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';

    XMLRequest := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                  '<AdCourierAPI>'+
                  '    <Method>ListChannels</Method>'+
                  '    <APIKey>'+APIKEY+'</APIKey>'+
                  '    <Account>'+
                  '        <UserName>'+AUserName+'</UserName>'+
                  '        <Password>'+APassword+'</Password>'+
                  '    </Account>'+
                  '</AdCourierAPI>';

    ASource.Text := XMLRequest;
    Result := HTTP.Post(APIURL, ASource);
  finally
    SSL.Free;
    HTTP.Free;
    ASource.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How exactly are you obtaining the string which the server "sees"? Maybe there's a conversion in there somewhere. Also, how are you formatting this API Key? You don't have to show us your key, but does it have any special characters in it which XML may not like?

Comment: On another note, you won't have to worry about this sort of thing if you use one of the many XML tools available in Delphi.

Comment: Please note that the server response is complaining about the very first line of the request body, so it would not have even reached the part specifying the APIKey, and this is to do with encoding for a HTTP request rather than XML in particular, but that's besides the point. I found the answer myself.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said you don't have to show it to us. Just wondering if it had special characters in it which XML may not like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of `Post()` to begin with.

You are using the overloaded version of `Post()` that accepts a `TStrings` as input.  That version is intended for posting HTML webforms in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, where the `TStrings` is expected to contain `name=value` strings that get encoded according to W3C's rules for submitting webforms.  That is why you are seeing your XML being encoded the way it is.

You need to use the other overloaded version of `Post()` that accepts a `TStream` as input.  The `TStream` data will be transmitted as-is.

Try this:

```
function TBroadBeanAPI.ListChannels(const AUserName, APassword: String): String;
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  ASource: TStringStream;
  XMLRequest: String;
begin
  Result := '';
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(HTTP);
    HTTP.IOHandler := SSL;
    HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
    HTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';

    XMLRequest := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                  '<AdCourierAPI>'+
                  '    <Method>ListChannels</Method>'+
                  '    <APIKey>'+APIKEY+'</APIKey>'+
                  '    <Account>'+
                  '        <UserName>'+AUserName+'</UserName>'+
                  '        <Password>'+APassword+'</Password>'+
                  '    </Account>'+
                  '</AdCourierAPI>';

    ASource := TStringStream.Create(XMLRequest, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Result := HTTP.Post(APIURL, ASource);
    finally
      ASource.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

On a side note, you are not encoding `APIKEY`, `AUserName`, or `APassword` when building your XML.  If they contain reserved characters, they must be escaped/encoded per XML formatting rules.  So watch out for that.  You should be using a real XML engine to build your XML, rather than using string concatenations.  Otherwise, at lease add an XML-compliant encoding function so you can concatenate properly formatted strings.

Comment: Thanks Remy. That explains things better. Was the first time I've tried using Indy and the code I used was based on an answer to another SO question. I'll certainly be making changes to ensure robustness when I come to flesh out the functions but this was mainly a test to see if I could use their API from Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to turn off [hoForceEncodeParams] in HTTPOptions of the TIdHTTP object. This can be done thusly:

```
HTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
```

Comment: Yes. It was a really simple answer but if you are creating TIdHTTP objects in code rather than dropping them on a form, you won't see that option being set on by default.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  The wrong version of `Post()` is being used in the first place.